# how to make a tmemo and Tedit with a transparent background?

Tags: delphi, canvas, transparency, onpaint

how to make a tmemo and Tedit with a transparent background? or 
add image background on it's canvas. that workable in both Delphi7 up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no actual answer to the question, but I know that TJvMemo from JVCL allows you to set it to transparent. Maybe you could just use that component? If not, you could check how it works.

Comment: @swein: In this case: Because you might not want to add several thousand lines of code of the jcl/jvcl to your project. OTOH: I rarely write a program without the jvcl.

Comment: +1. dummzeuch because most of the component has a lot of addon units that is not usable on my appication. I better use the most basic as much as posible.

Comment: In my testing with D7 on Win7, the text background of TJvMemo  is not transparent, only the areas that are not covered by the text lines are transparent. 
Link here:http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5123

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [window-less Rich Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787609(VS.85).aspx). There might be easier solutions, however.