# Is there a transparent TMemo or TRichEdit VCL control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make a tmemo and Tedit with a transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714495/how-to-make-a-tmemo-and-tedit-with-a-transparent-background)
>   However, the previous answer about TJvMemo is not useful for this Q. More components wanted.

Hi,

Is there a 3rd party transparent TMemo or RichEdit VCL? Thanks! If no, any hint as to make a TRichEdit transparent? E.g. the TImage behind it is shown instead as the background of the RichEdit or memo control.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned the duplicated question and why I'm not satisfied with the answers given there. For the first answer, the TJvMemo.Transparent doesn't work under Win7 anymore; For the 2nd answer, It's Windows API, not a VCL control, but I'm looking for a VCL control.

Comment: Voted to open this Q again because the previous Q doesn't have a proper answer. A different control is required.

Comment: +1 to reopen. I haven't even been successful to have proper transparency with 'TJvMemo' on earlier version OSes.

Comment: Thanks for reopening the question, you guys are nice and I really appreciate your are contributing your knowledge & time in the SO Delphi community!

Comment: @Edwin: Most VCL controls (`TButton`, `TEdit`, `TListBox`, `TMemo`, `TRichEdit`, `TComboBox`, `TMainMenu`, `TStatusBar`, ..., ...) are just wrappers around the Windows API and the windows standard controls. There are only a few exceptions, such as `TStringGrid`.

Comment: @Edwin - The question is not open yet, I'd guess the `closed` in the brackets would be removed then. It requires 5 votes to reopen a question (which at this time it's got 3).

Comment: @Sertac, oh, I see it now, now only one's left :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual needs (what you want to see through the control) you might find functionality offered by LMD ElPack component suite usable. That controls (including TElEdit/TElMemo) offer both transparency and custom backgrounds.

Comment: No idea why someone down-rated this, it exactly answers the question.

Comment: @Larry: I didn't downvote, but I understand why it was voted down. And if you think about it for a while, I am positive you can guess a reason too.

Comment: I'm still thinking, but haven't hit it yet.  I don't think it's the author trying to sell his own components and even if so it would still answer the question.  The user didn't ask for a free component.  And if the problem is the duplicate question, that should be held against the OP.  I'm feeling a little stupid today, I guess.

Comment: The downvoter most likely reacted to the fact that Eugene posted an answer even though he knew this was a duplicate. First of all, as this question should be closed, any new answers should be posted in the old question, not here! And, secondly, it is really easy rep if you could just copy the answers of the old question and just pretend you didn't know of the duplicate.

Comment: @Andreas such approach is badly broken. Duplicate question doesn't mean "the same answers". Answers change over time and if the question is closed as a duplicate, the OP has no way to get more responses than the ones that were given in the previous question.  Moreover, the OP might be unsatisfied by previous answers or looking for other solutions or other approaches to the problem (or even different aspect of the problem).

Comment: Eugene is right, actually I read that duplicated question, and I should have mentioned it in my question and I'm not satisfied by the answers of that previous question.